# Filter the rows based on the missing values on the specific set columns - pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have data frame as shown below

```
ID       Type         Desc         D_N    D_A    C_N     C_A
1        Edu          Education    3      100    NaN     NaN
1        Bank         In_Pay       NaN    NaN    NaN     900
1        Eat          Food         4      200    NaN     NaN
1        Edu          Education    NaN    NaN    NaN     NaN
1        Bank         NaN          NaN    NaN    4       700
1        Eat          Food         NaN    NaN    NaN     NaN
2        Edu          Education    NaN    NaN    1       100
2        Bank         NaN          NaN    NaN    8       NaN
2        NaN          Food         4      NaN    NaN     NaN
3        Edu          Education    NaN    NaN    NaN     NaN
3        Bank         NaN          2      300    NaN     NaN
3        Eat          Food         NaN    140    NaN     NaN
```

From the above df, I would like to filter the rows where exactly one of the columns `D_N`, `D_A`, `C_N` and `C_A` has non zero.

Expected Output:

```
ID       Type         Desc         D_N    D_A    C_N     C_A
1        Bank         In_Pay       NaN    NaN    NaN     900
2        Bank         NaN          NaN    NaN    8       NaN
2        NaN          Food         4      NaN    NaN     NaN
3        Eat          Food         NaN    140    NaN     NaN
```

I tried the below code but that does not work.

```
df[df.loc[:, ["D_N", "D_A", "C_N", "C_A"]].isna().sum(axis=1).eq(1)]
```

Comment: Non zero or Non-NaN ?  They are different.  Non-NaN doesn't necessarily be non-zero.

Comment: @SeaBean non NaN

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.count`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.count.html) for count values excluded missing values:

```
df1 = df[df[["D_N", "D_A", "C_N", "C_A"]].count(axis=1).eq(1)]
print (df1)
    ID  Type    Desc  D_N    D_A  C_N    C_A
1    1  Bank  In_Pay  NaN    NaN  NaN  900.0
7    2  Bank     NaN  NaN    NaN  8.0    NaN
8    2   NaN    Food  4.0    NaN  NaN    NaN
11   3   Eat    Food  NaN  140.0  NaN    NaN
```

Your solution is possible modify with test non missing values:

```
df1 = df[df[["D_N", "D_A", "C_N", "C_A"]].notna().sum(axis=1).eq(1)]
```